# Time taken for ball to reach down is more?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, projectile, drag

If we consider a practial situation, where air resistance exists, why does a ball/object take more time to come down than to go up?
This seems contradicting to me at the first glance, but I am pretty sure this might be due to the direction of air resistance acting.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Air resistance is the same in every direction of motion. Can you clarify situations where you find that the fime falling down is larger than going up?

Comment: Since you mention directions... you can imagine there are only 2 forces on the object.  Can you describe in what directions these two forces are on the way up?   And on the way down?

Comment: I suspect that the process of throwing the ball is the main difference. For throwing, the ball starts with a velocity v0 when let go. At the turning point, the ball has a velocity v=0 and is accelerated by gravity. But you need to further clarify the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Time of a ball going up and down with air resistance](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/40778/)

Comment: It is an instructive, yet mathematically intensive, problem to go and compute the time taken for the upward journey and for the downward journey, assuming only quadratic air drag. It is much easier for the linear air drag. But in both cases, the result is the same, as expected by everybody using other physical reasoning than just directly integrating.

Comment: @PeterSanctus Yes, it is actually due to the direction of gravity. I meant real life situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While going up, both - air resistance and gravity is stopping a ball, so to say decelerating force is $m\alpha=mg+F_{drag} $, while going down - air drag tries to stop, but gravity does not - it accelerates, so overall effect is that air resistance is reducing gravitational acceleration as per $ma=mg-F_{drag} $. And because air drag $\propto v^2$ at some point object will reach terminal velocity, as per equilibrium condition $mg=F_{drag}$.

Hence due to reduced down acceleration and to the maximum possible down speed, body has more time fly down than up. This is why parachutes is so valuable,- they slows down movement so much that it's safe to land on foots.

Comment: Thanks for the well explained answer, I have understood it now.